# how do I create a loop based on a start date and end date

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, date-range

I have the following table:

[image]

and what I want is to do a loop for every other 10 days based on reading_date, start with min(reading_date) until max(reading_date).
In the end I will need to bring the corresponding data to new date :

just as in the picture below :
[image]

Does anyone how to do this in hive sql?

It's so easy in C++, but for some reason I cannot get it to work in hive.
I really need all the help I can get. Thank you!

```
t1.reading_date t1.use_date t1.name t1.reading_pct
12/17/2019  12/11/2019  file1   75.00915527
12/22/2019  12/11/2019  file1   75.5859375
12/27/2019  12/11/2019  file1   76.90429688
1/1/2020    12/11/2019  file1   74.29199219
1/2/2020    12/11/2019  file1   64.93835449
1/7/2020    12/11/2019  file1   65.10620117
1/12/2020   12/11/2019  file1   66.90063477
1/17/2020   12/11/2019  file1   66.47033691
1/22/2020   12/11/2019  file1   66.35131836
1/27/2020   12/11/2019  file1   59.61303711
```

```
new(t1.reading_date)    t1.use_date t1.name t1.reading_pct
12/17/2019  12/11/2019  file1   75.00915527
12/27/2019  12/11/2019  file1   76.90429688
1/7/2020    12/11/2019  file1   65.10620117
1/17/2020   12/11/2019  file1   66.47033691
1/27/2020   12/11/2019  file1   59.61303711
```

Comment: could you please post your data as text with dates in yyyy-MM-dd format?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, see comments in the code. Could not test because you have posted data as picture. Debug it yourself:

```
With minmaxdt as (
select min(reading_date) as mindt, max(reading_date) as maxdt from your_table
),

date_range as 
(--this query generates date range
select date_add (mindt,s.i+10) as dt 
  from minmaxdt
       lateral view posexplode(split(space(int(datediff(maxdt,mindt) div 10)),' ')) s as i,x 
) 

--Join with date range 
select reading_date, use_date, name, reading_pct
  from your_table t1
       inner join date_range dr on t1.reading_date=dr.dt
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I've got this error message. I am fairly new to hive: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: line 9:37 Wrong arguments '10': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFSpace with (bigint). Possible choices: _FUNC_(int)

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? I tried int instead of div and still with an error

Comment: @Dia edited abswer - added int() Also you can try `cast(datediff(maxdt,mindt) div 10  as int)` to convert bigint to int